# SQL SELECT Statement Using Three Tables

Tags: sql, etl

I am trying to write a SQL Select statement to port some data from a Sybase environment to a MongoDB environment and I'm just trying to figure out the correct syntax to involve three different tables.

Basically what I need to do is do an INNER JOIN on two tables, and then do a matching check against a 3rd table. The three table names are "ar_notes", "customer_service_xref" and "service_notes_details"

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM ar_notes arn
      LEFT JOIN customer_service_xref csx ON arn.customer_service_xref_id = csx.id_number
      WHERE arn.visit_date = service_notes_details.date_of_visit
```

This doesn't work. I get a correlation error.

What should the syntax look like when involving three tables like this?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: My question is more about syntax. Is the above syntax theoretically correct?

Comment: Do another JOIN for the third table? I.e. `select columns from t1 join t2 on ... join t3 on ... where... `

Comment: @GordonLinoff `to a MongoDB environment` ... do you know Mongo syntax? (I don't :-( ).

Comment: No need to worry about Mongo here. I'm concerned with the correct SQL sybase syntax. One can run SQL Anywhere in Mongo once I have the correct SQL syntax.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . Mongo SQL is relatively similar to SQL.  However, if the data is in Sybase, then the code should be in Sybase.

Comment: @jarlh, you mean like this?:
SELECT * FROM ar_notes arn
     LEFT JOIN customer_service_xref csx ON arn.customer_service_xref_id = csx.id_number
      JOIN service_notes_details WHERE arn.visit_date = service_notes_details.date_of_visit

Comment: Almost, but put the last join condition in an ON clause instead of in WHERE.

Comment: Ah, okay. Cool, that generated results for me. Much appreciated.

Comment: So, just to clarify, is there no way to match a column value in one table against a column value in another table without doing a JOIN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you need an INNER JOIN among three tables but your query does a LEFT JOIN between two and tries another join in the WHERE clause without refering that table in the FROM clause.

To just fix your query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM service_notes_details snd, ar_notes arn
INNER JOIN customer_service_xref csx ON arn.customer_service_xref_id = csx.id_number
WHERE arn.visit_date = snd.date_of_visit
```

This is what you should use in current SQL syntax:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ar_notes arn
INNER JOIN customer_service_xref csx ON arn.customer_service_xref_id = csx.id_number
INNER JOIN service_notes_details ON arn.visit_date = service_notes_details.date_of_visit
```

To be clear, this will only return lines in `ar_notes` that have corresponding values in `customer_service_xref` (joining by `customer_service_xref_id`) and in `service_notes_details`(joining by `visit_date`). Your original query, using `LEFT JOIN` would return lines from `ar_notes` even if there was no matching `customer_service_xref_id`.

Comment: So, just to clarify, is there no way to match a column value in one table against a column value in another table without doing a JOIN?

Comment: Well, it depends on what you want to do with the match. You can embed a sub-query in the `SELECT` clause querying a different table by a value from the main query. That avoids a `JOIN` clause in some situations, but it is ugly if it is not actually needed. Perhaps you should clarify your question?

Comment: I need to make sure the `visit_date` from one table is the same value as `date_of_visit` in another table, but I don't actually need any data from that 3rd table.

Comment: The query in my answer does that, but if you don’t like adding an extra `INNER JOIN` you can add the `service_notes_details` in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: What would that look like?

Comment: @Muirik the `select *` will return all columns from all joined tables; to limit which columns you wish to return then update Ipacheco's query to return only the columns you want, eg: `select arn.customer_service_xref_id, arn.some_other_column, csx.yet_another_column from ....`